# Turning off the UPS when PC is off

Tags: ups

I have a UPS to which I've plugged my PC and 2 monitors. Today while my PC and monitors were turned off and the UPS on and plugged, a power outage happened for roughly an hour.

It made me think about this:
What happens during a power outage if both the UPS and monitors/PC plugged to it are off while the UPS stays plugged?

Is it safer to let the UPS on at all times, or should I turn it off and leave it plugged when I'm done using the PC?

Comment: Better just leave the UPS powered on and not think about it. In fact, turning a UPS on and off will lower the battery life of the UPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the UPS is not only to power your devices in case of
a power outage, but also to protect your local devices from any
power surge.

You may safely leave your UPS connected when your other devices are
turned off, as it can protect itself. Leaving it on will also assure
a full battery so it can better do its job.

Comment: Perhaps someone could enlighten me as to why leaving a UPS plugged in was downvoted and the same as the accepted answer. Such action was astonishing

Comment: @John: I can't help you with that. Downvotes are not always comprehensible.

Comment: @John - By deleting your answer, anyone that might have found it helpful, cannot upvote it.

Comment: @John: Undelete your answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Hi Harry - done - my answer is back

Comment: @John : Enjoy .

Comment: You are always very nice - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The UPS has a battery inside.  Leave it plugged in as is normal to ensure (a) it is operating properly and (b) allows the battery to charge.

No need to unplug and (best practice) you should not.

Answer (score -2):

It shouldn't be any more or less safe. I leave mine on all the time and plugged in to keep the battery charged and keep my devices readily available.